# Printing the Request and Reponse in the HTML Report File

Tags: citrus-framework

I have a customized reporting integrated with the framework. Where I have implemented `TestReport extends AbstractTestListener implements TestReporter` class.

This is the steps which is responsible to Print the Report in Html File

```
        ET=ETTe.startTest(test.getName());
        ET.log(LogStatus.PASS, test.toString());
        ET.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Pass");
```

Any way by using `test.toString()` I can get the data which has been sent to the server. For printing the response do we have any method or way around for it?

Regards
BJ

Answer (score 0):

You should also implement `com.consol.citrus.report.MessageListener` interface with `onInboundMessage(...)` and `onOutboundMessage(...)` in order to get access to the exchanged message data in your reporter.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Is there a Method Available to Either Get the Status Code or Any Customized Message from the Response and Print it into My Custom Reporting

Comment: In generic message object the status code is a normal header entry with key "citrus_http_status_code". You can access the generic header on the message object using that key with `getHeader()`. Also when using http message transport you may cast the message object to an HttpMessage that provides more comfortable access to the status code.